# Creating an associative table in Prisma Schema

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I'm trying to model the following using Prisma for a personal project I'm working on.

[image: My intended schema]

The following schema for this I have put together is the following (I've removed some of the unnecessary session tables):

```
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id            String     @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  SpotList      SpotList[]
}

// SpotSpot tables

model SpotList {
  id               Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId           String
  name             String?
  description      String?
  public           Boolean
  createdAt        DateTime           @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime           @updatedAt
  User             User               @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  SpotListLocation SpotListLocation[]
}

model SpotListLocation {
  list       SpotList     @relation(fields: [listId], references: [id])
  listId     Int
  location   SpotLocation @relation(fields: [locationId], references: [id])
  locationId Int

  @@id([listId, locationId])
}

model SpotLocation {
  id               Int                                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String?
  description      String?
  coords           Unsupported("geometry(Point, 4326)")
  createdAt        DateTime                             @default(now())
  updatedAt        DateTime                             @updatedAt
  SpotListLocation SpotListLocation[]
}
```

My question was basically two things:

1. Does my initial db design look sensible?
2. Is my schema a faithful representation of my design?

Bearing in mind, it's just a personal project for learning backend and DB mostly. I don't need it to be the most performant thing in the world. I just don't want it to be completely wrong :)

Comment: Your design looks good, just a sidenote that as SpotLocation model has an Unsupported field, the generated prismaclient for spotlocation model would not have a create method.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for commenting. Yeah I wanted to do some location stuff so I thought I'd use PostGIS so that means I have to use $rawQuery for that table, as like you said no create.